# jQuery Code Completion Style Textbox Typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, code-completion

Does anyone know of a function or plugin to jQuery (or pure JS, doesn't matter) that will perform a code completion type function? But with change-able options? Like I want to start typing `[b]` and when I add that last bracket, it automatically adds `[/b]` after the cursor? If anyone knows anything like this, it would be great and a gigantic time saver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [JQuery Caret Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret), you could use some code like:

```
<textarea id="codeInput" cols="80" rows="50">content</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tagDict = {
      "[b]" : "[/b]",
      "[c]" : "[/c]",
      "[d]" : "[/d]"
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#codeInput').keyup(function () {
            var test = $(this).val();
            var tagStart = test.substr(test.length - 3, 3);
            if (tagDict[tagStart]) {
                $(this).val(test + tagDict[tagStart]);            
                $(this).caret(test.length, test.length);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

It's not perfect, but it could be a start for a complete code completion function.

Comment: Oh my God! Thanks so much! I will award the bounty when SO lets me, which it says in 3 hours